# ArcGIS error with Python Toolbox that imports matplotlib?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.5, python-toolbox, matplotlib, 64bit

Recently upgraded to 10.5 ArcGIS. Custom ArcPy Toolbox (pyt) shows the red-x error and will not load. Going to "Check Syntax.." results in this:

```
   File "[from custom ArcPy Tool .py file]"...
     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 129, in <module>
    from matplotlib.externals.six.moves.urllib.request import urlopen
   File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\externals\six.py", line 90, in __get__
    result = self._resolve()
   File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\externals\six.py", line 158, in _resolve
    module = _import_module(self.mod)
   File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\externals\six.py", line 80, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
   File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.5\Lib\urllib2.py", line 94, in <module>
    import httplib
   File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.5\Lib\httplib.py", line 72, in <module>
    import socket
   File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.5\Lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Maybe it's normal, but I do notice the stack trace goes from the 32-bit to 64-bit installs of python. 64-bit should be default I think as I installed background geoprocessing and have it enabled.

Seems to be specific to matplotlib as other custom PYTs load fine, but if I add `import matplotlib` they also run into same error. There is a matplotlib in the site-packages for 64-bit python. Just to be safe I upgraded it via pip to the latest.

Everything is version 10.5.1.7333, including Background Geoprocessing (64-bit). I did a repair install of ArcGIS 10.5 and Background Geoprocessing with no effect. All PYTHONPATH environment variables are pointing to 64-bit python.

Comment: Did you install the 64bit MatPlotLib? The import error looks like it can find the file but it's not a 32bit DLL as expected. You have mentioned 64bit background processing but *are you actually using it?* If you're using *check syntax* it's likely to be 32bit, same if you're running from command line... I would recommend ditching 64bit background geoprocessing altogether, it causes too many complications like this where half your imports are from 64bit and the other half are from 32bit python.

Comment: Some other solutions are found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898131/matplotlib-1-3-0-importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-applicati Also consider downloading the premade windows binaries from here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ (They tend to work a lot better). Also try running your script outside of ArcGIS as a standalone; Python GUIs crash inside of the Arc environment.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, it's 64-bit and background processing is enabled. Imports shouldn't be coming from 32-bit at all since 64-bit should be used. This toolbox works with lots of big data, 64-bit is basically a necessity. If python was run from the command line it's definitely 64-bit as I checked the environment variables. Seems like it will run in 64-bit but Arc checks syntax in 32-bit which raises the error before I can even load the toolbox. I don't know why Arc likes to switch between 32/64-bit python willy-nilly, but this wasn't an issue before I upgraded to 10.5 (from 10.2).

Comment: You can see from the paths that it's bouncing from 64bit to 32bit libs, do you get these errors when you execute from CMD? It may be something in your %PATH% and/or %PYTHONPATH% system environment variables that's forcing the read from 32bit libs.. you can change these variables *before importing* using os.environ.set("PATH","semi-colon delimited list of folders to search") Note: this only changes the path variable for the currently executing python session not for all time or any other processes so it's safe to change without doing permanent damage.

Comment: Every instance of Python in PATH or PYTHON_PATH points to ArcGISx6410.5. This includes for user and system. Running the toolbox from CMD with the python command results in no errors, loads, then since it's not a command line tool, exits without doing anything. I'm sure I could whip up a programmatic way of running it via a .py script which would run, but that would defeat the purpose of the ArcToolbox. At this point I'm just trying a uninstall/reinstall of ArcGIS entirely, but the same setup worked w/o a problem for coworkers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it, though I'm not happy with the solution entirely, it works..

A complete clean reinstall of ArcGIS caused Numpy to fail (in 32-bit). Which ended up breaking every ArcPy Toolbox since ArcPy requires Numpy. While this seemed worse, it sort of gave me some direction.

The basic understanding I have now is that ArcGIS runs in 32-bit python regardless. When running the tool with background processing, it can use 64-bit to run the actual tool, but it initially loads and checks the syntax of the tool in 32-bit. So you have to make sure both your 32-bit and 64-bit Python instances are working with your tool, even if it only actually runs in the 64-bit version.

First thing I did was delete my system's `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. Having specific paths to the 64-bit Python's Lib folder was probably causing the weird jumping back and forth between 32/64-bit folderpaths when calling libraries. This might come to bite me later, as I believe either I or some program I installed had to create it for a good reason when doing other Python projects, but for now nothing seems broken so we'll roll with it.

Then I did a repair installation of ArcGIS again just to be safe. Probably not necessary step but detailing to be comprehensive.

Now while I could import matplotlib in 32-bit Python normally (e.g. via Python in CMD or PyCharm), the ArcPy Toolbox still had a "Check Syntax.." error about `IO Error: Invalid file descriptor`. While I'm not sure specifically what that error referenced, the line in question was only a print statement (printing a non-fatal warning). Something about how ArcGIS loads the library probably causes an issue with this, even though it loads fine in the regular Python environment.

`C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py` @ about line 1080.

```
    else:
        print("""
Bad key "%s" on line %d in
%s.
You probably need to get an updated matplotlibrc file from
http://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/matplotlibrc.template
or from the matplotlib source distribution""" % (key, cnt, fname),
                  file=sys.stderr)
```

I tried just deleting parts (like `file=sys.stderr`, all the way to just making it `print "Bad key"`) but no matter what something about the print was tripping up ArcGIS (must somehow be parsing console outputs?). Since it's not technically vital code, I just deleted the whole else clause.

Bit hacky, but now it works anyways. I suppose other option is to delve into updating matplotlibrc, but I found this way simpler -- though I did try updating matplotlib to the latest via pip (yes, forcing on 32-bit python), but didn't fix anything.

Comment: just intall the library in both 32bit and 62bit instances with pip no?

Comment: I think the bigger thing was deleting the PYTHONPATH envir. variable. The error wasn't so much the lack of matplotlib (in either), as I think it was there, so much as the imports flopping between 32/64-bit paths. While I code/program entirely in 64-bit Python so normally that's fine, ArcGIS does use 32-bit at least for the basic GUI and loading toolboxes it seems (though not sure why it was fine in 10.2 but broke in 10.5). Still not sure what I needed the PYTHONPATH var for, but so far nothing is broken (knocks on wood).